# How to push same screen two time in react native navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

**I want the previous screen data should not changes.**

I have try to use duplicate **dummy screen** with same component and also pass different keys and params, it's working but when i change some data in current screen it change into last previous screen as well.

```
Navigation.registerComponent('Home', () => HomeComponent);
Navigation.registerComponent('HomeCopy', () => HomeComponent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just register the component once.
Whenever you wan't the home screen you do this from another screen:

```
this.props.navigation.push('Home');
```

you can do this as many times and get as many copies of the home screen as you want

Comment: I have try this but this is related to react navigation and i have used react native navigation.
if you can help me out for react native navigation that would to great.

Comment: Oh sorry, my mistake. Why don't you use react navigation instead? Seems like it better fits your needs.